# Conditional mean on uncorrelated stochastic variable 2

Tags: probability-theory

This question is a follow up from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/626958/conditional-mean-on-uncorrelated-stochastic-variable). I was in doubt if to add it in my previous question, but thought it unfair to the great answers I had received.

Let $X,Y$ be stochastic variables such that $\text{Cov}(X,f(Y))=0$ for all bounded measurable functions. Would that then imply that $E[X|Y]=E[X]$? If so why? (reference, proof, hint - anything will do)

Comment: Yes, follows directly from the definition of conditional expectation--which one are you using?

Comment: Great! $E[X|Y]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable, integrable and $E[E[X|Y],A]=E[X,A]$ for all $A\in \sigma(Y)$.

Comment: Right--and thus...?

Comment: $E[X]$ is integrable and $\sigma(Y)$-measurable obviously. Ergo we just need to show that $E[X,A]=E[E[X],A]=E[X]P(A)$ where last equality is since $E[X]$ is constant. If $A\in \sigma(Y)$ we can set $f=1_A$ measurable and bounded to conclude, using the assumption, exactly that $E[X,A]=E[X]P(A)$ which concludes the proof. Thanks Did!

Comment: You may want to post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E[X]$ is integrable and $\sigma(Y)$-measurable obviously. Ergo we just need to show that $E[X,A]=E[E[X],A]=E[X]P(A)$ where last equality is since E[X] is constant. If $A\in \sigma(Y)$ we can set f=1A measurable and bounded to conclude, using the assumption, exactly that $E[X,A]=E[X]P(A)$ which concludes the proof. Thanks Did!