# A case when uncorrelatedness imply mean independence.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have some questions about understanding [a previous post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/627846/1281) by another user.

Let $X,Y$ be random variables. Prove that if $\text{Cov}(X,f(Y))=0$ for all bounded measurable function $f$, then $E[X|Y]=E[X]$.

> $E[X]$ is integrable and $\sigma(Y)$-measurable obviously. **Ergo we just need to show that $$E[X,A]=E[E[X],A]=E[X]P(A),$$** where last equality is since E[X] is constant. If $A\in \sigma(Y)$ we can set f=1A measurable and bounded to conclude, using the assumption, exactly that $E[X,A]=E[X]P(A)$ which concludes the proof.

1. I wonder why "we just need to show that
   $E[X,A]=E[E[X],A]=E[X]P(A)$"?

   - What is the meaning/definition of the notation $E[X,A]$, where $X$ is a random variable, and $A$ is an event?
   - Why setting $f=1_A$, $\text{Cov}(X,f(Y))=0$ leads to $E[X,A]=E[X]P(A)$?
2. Is the reverse true? I.e. if $E[X|Y]=E[X]$, then
   $\text{Cov}(X,f(Y))=0$ for all bounded measurable function $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: Point 1. being purely the definition forces the question: how do YOU define conditional expectation?

Comment: [Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Formal_definition) YOU are. :)

Comment: Hence WHICH point is not COMPLETELY obvious to you here?

Comment: Those points in the bulletted questions. I studied something before, which doesn't mean I understand and am able to use it completely and correctly.

Comment: Why are you avoiding to answer my very precise query?

Comment: And why are you editing your comments after they were answered?

Comment: I am not doing anything, and haven't had activity in the past half an hour for having to deal with something else, and hoping will have time to come back to find out why I avoided your query, and address that. What "comments"? Sometimes you assume me (and maybe others) to know something or what you are referring to, but actually I (and others) don't. Sorry.

Comment: You did edit a comment, to tone it down (which was a wise thing to do, by the way).

Comment: It was pure fun and imitating your comment (not only you can do that), not actually shouting.

Comment: I see that suddenly you are perfetly aware of which comment of yours was problematic. All this is not very coherent. But what about the maths? Still determined to play word games instead of *reading* the definitions?

Comment: The "not very coherent" comes from the present tense using in "why are you editing your comments", and from not understanding which questions "were answered". Still bothered by something else, and my mind can't focus, but ironically can deal with the word game which I will now stop.

Comment: @Did: I edited my post, trying to pin down why I don't understand the post.