# When will $E(X\mid Y)=EX$ be true?

Tags: probability

A maybe easier question:

Can you find an example that satisfies

> $X$ and $Y$ are not independent, but $E(X\mid Y) = EX$.

---

My actual question:

In what cases (other than independence between $X$ and $Y$), will $E(X\mid Y)=EX$ be true?

The weaker the case, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: It is easier to provide examples than a general rule

Comment: Edited for examples. @Henry

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want the expected value of $X$ to be some particular number $\mu$.  For every value that the random variable $Y$ could take, pick some probability distribution for which the expected value exists.  If $W$ is a random variable with that distribution, then let $W-\mathbb EW + \mu$ be the value of $X$ when $Y$ assumes the particular value concerned.  Then $\mathbb E(X\mid Y) =\mu$ with probability $1$, and $\mathbb E(X)=\mu$.  But $X$ and $Y$ are far from independent if you picked a different distribution for each value that $Y$ could take.

Concrete example: Say you want $\mathbb EX$ to be $6$.  Say $\displaystyle Y=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{with probability }1/2, \\ 1 & \text{with probability }1/2. \end{cases}$  If $Y=0$, let $X$ be $6$ plus a standard normal random variable.  If $Y = 1$, let $X$ be $6\pm1$, each with probability $1/2$.  Then $\mathbb E(X\mid Y)=6$ with probability $1$ and $\mathbb E(X)=6$, but $X$ and $Y$ are far from being independent.

Comment: Do you mean $X=W -\mathbb{E}(W|Y)+\mu$?

Comment: No.... There's no such thing as $\mathbb E(W\mid Y)$ until the definition has been presented that appears later.

Comment: If $g(w)=\mathbb E(Y\mid W=w)$ is meaningful, then $g(W)=\mathbb E(Y\mid W)$ is also meaningful for all well behaved $Y$ and $W$ (e.g. when $\mathbb E(Y)$ exists and is finite).

Comment: @Henry : If that's intended as an objection to what I said, I think it's mistaken.  It is true that if $\mathbb E(Y\mid W=w)$ is defined for every value of $w$ then the random variable $\mathbb E(Y\mid W)$ is defined.  What I was saying was that (1) the definitions needed to understand what $\mathbb E(W\mid Y)$ means had not yet been given where I mentioned $W-\mathbb E(W)+\mu$, and (2) there's no need for anything except $W-\mathbb E(W)+\mu$ at that point.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the conditional expectation is a function of the conditioning variable $E(X\mid Y) =g(Y)$  When this function is a constant, then (iff) $E(X\mid Y) =E(X)$. You can't say much more, in general.

Here I give an [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627056/312).

Comment: I just wonder something related. Assume $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated and zero mean (or with some equal mean). Then is there any bound for the supremum of $E[X|Y]$?