# $E (XY)=E (xE (Y|X)) $ - is this always true?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

By the law of total expectation,

$$E \left(XY\right) =E \left[E \left(XY\mid X=x\right)\right]=\dots$$

Now, because $X=x $ is a constant and by linearity of expectation,

$$\dots=E [xE (Y|X=x)]$$

So we got that no matter what $X,Y$ are: $E (XY)=E[xE (Y|X)] $.

Is this true? Is my reasoning right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your reasoning is basically right but your notation is objectionable. What does "$X=x$  is a constant" mean? If $x$ is a constant, then it would came outside the outer expectation - and the law of total expectation would not apply. You should simply write

$$E (X\, Y) =E (E(X \, Y \mid X))=E (X \, E(Y\mid X))$$

This is indeed true for any $X,Y$. And, by the way, it leads directly to the conclusiont that "unpredictableness implies uncorrelatedness", or $E(Y|X)=E(Y) \implies E(X Y) = E(X) E(Y)$ (but [not the reverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/627056/312))

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the answer I was hoping to get

Comment: @leonbloy, what is the proof of these equalities?

Comment: For the first one, see the [tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) - write $E[E[Z |X]]=E[Z]$ and then choose $Z=XY$. The rest are quite direct, I think.