# When does $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2)$ imply $Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$?

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, independence

$Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$, by which I mean that $Y$ is independent of $X_1$ conditional on $X_2$, implies $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2)$. However, the reversed implication does not hold in general since conditional expectations do not in general fully characterize conditional distributions. Nevertheless, under certain assumptions, the reversed implication is true. For example, suppose $Y$ is a dummy variable. Then the distribution of $Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$ is characterized by $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=P(Y=1\mid X_1,X_2)$, which gives the reversed implication. But I believe this is not the only example. So, when exactly does $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2)$ imply $Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$? For example, if $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2)$ imply $Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$, does this imply that some property about the random variables is necessarily satisfied?

I found this exercise in a book on causal inference, and I was not sure what kind of answer the author was after.

One idea is that whether the implication is true or not is related to if moments other than the first moment of $Y$ given $(X_1,X_2)$ do not depend on $X_1$.

Comment: This feels like a "for what kind of distribution does zero correlation means independence" question. If this is true then you will probably get that $X_1$ and $Y$ needs to be jointly Gaussian given $X_2$ or such.

Comment: @P.Quinton I believe that you do not need them to be jointly Gaussian since I believe it is sufficient that $Y$ is a 0-1 dummy variable.

Comment: Didn't you get the implicancies reversed ? unpredictable implies uncorrelated, not the other way. https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1615161/312

Comment: @leonbloy No. The implication I am considering does not hold in general, but it holds under certain assumptions.

Comment: What I'm saying is precisely that the implication that holds in general is the other one.
"However, the reversed implication does not hold in general" It's the other way.

Comment: @leonbloy Are you saying that $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2)$ implies $Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$...? Please be more specific. I think you might take my notation for independence as notation for zero covariance.

Comment: Ah, $Y\perp X$ means $Y,X$ are independent in your notation? I guessed it meant orthogonal (uncorrelated). Then I said nothing.

Answer (score -1):

The question is essentially equivalent (with an added conditional) to the following one:

The implicancy $E[X | Y ] = E[X] \implies X \perp Y$ (where $\perp$ denotes independence) is in general false. Under which additional assumptions it's true?

There is no general answer to this. Practically speaking, there are two important cases:

- $(X,Y)$ are jointly gaussian (not the same as "$X,Y$ are both gaussian"!)
- $(X,Y)$ are both Bernoulli (takes values in $\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} $)

This, because in both cases above no correlation implies independence (and no correlation is weaker than $E[X | Y ] = E[X]$).

Assuming the first case is the most typical/important, going back to the original question, we can assert:

If $(Y,X_1)$ conditioned on $X_2$ are jointly gaussian, then $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2) \implies Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$

Or slightly simpler and more in particular:

If $(Y,X_1,X_2)$ are jointly gaussian, then $E(Y\mid X_1,X_2)=E(Y\mid X_2) \implies Y\perp X_1\mid X_2$

Comment: Thanks! But how do you know that there is no general answer to my question?

Comment: There can be no "general answer" to such a question. As the first comment says, This feels like a "for what kind of distribution does zero correlation means independence" question".  When only a subset of your universe exhibit some property P, the way to characterize that subset is simply: "the individuals that exhibit property P". There might exist some more elegant, concise, insightful descriptions, but you cannot "prove" that they don't exist.

Comment: One general answer would be that if the implication is true, then the random variables must satisfy some property. So I am still not satisfied with your answer, and I do not think it answers my question either.