# Counterexample for $E[X|Y]=E[X]$ implies $X$ and $Y$ independent

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

Statement: $E[X|Y]=E[X]$ implies $X$ and $Y$ independent.

I quite sure that it's not true, And I trying to find an Counterexample for this. but it's hard for me to find one.

Comment: See the following post: [Is there any counterexample to show that $X,Y$ are two random variables and $E(X\mid Y)=E(X)$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815227/is-there-any-counterexample-to-show-that-x-y-are-two-random-variables-and-ex?rq=1)

Comment: I didn't found it before. Thank you

Comment: After three rather basic questions about conditional expectations in the measure theory sense of the term... Do you have any textbook on the subject at your disposal? Otherwise, I can already predict the long string of elementary questions you are susceptible to ask about it...

Comment: @Did
I got one, but it seems not to have everything in it, and there are some that points that are not clear, and of course  there are questions which I need to figure, such as this one.
about those 3 questions, expect for the second one none of them seems to me basic.

Comment: The present one is explained in every decent source on the subject.