# Does E(X|Y)=E(X) implies independence between X and Y?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, independence

if anyone could help me with this doubt, it would be great! I know that independence between X and Y implies  E(X|Y)=E(X) and E(Y|X)=E(Y), but i really don't know if the opposite is valid.

Thank very much for your attention! Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any counterexample to show that $X,Y$ are two random variables and $E(X\mid Y)=E(X)$, but $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815227/is-there-any-counterexample-to-show-that-x-y-are-two-random-variables-and-ex)

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815227/is-there-any-counterexample-to-show-that-x-y-are-two-random-variables-and-ex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, for independence you need that fact for every function $g(X)$. If it only holds for the expected value then you usually say that variables are "mean-independent".

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $Y$ be a coin flip ($1$ wp $1/2$ and $-1$ wp $1/2$). Let $X=YU$ where $U$ is uniform $[-1,1]$ and independent of $Y$.