# Conditional independence vs independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, independence

Suppose I have a set of random variables $\left(A_j\right)_{j=1}^n$ such that

$\mathrm{Prob}[A_n=a_n;\ldots; A_1=a_1|A_0=a_0]=\prod_{j=1}^n\mathrm{Prob}[A_j=a_j]$

Are they independent of one another or just conditionally independent?

Comment: The natural approach would be to try to construct a counter-example: if you succeed then you have an answer; if you fail you may be able to see why you fail

Comment: This statement as it stays makes no sence, since the left hand side is basically a random variable and the right hand side only a real number. Also what do you denote by the intersection of random variables?

Comment: @a.s.graduatestudent I edited the question. The sign "$;$" denotes the joint probability. Hope it's better now

Comment: If you have independence of $(A_1,\dots,A_n)$ from $A_0$ then the formula above holds, however here you don't have independence nor conditional independence, this boils down to two facts:

1] You only condition on one event given by $A_0 = a_0$
2] Generally $E[X \mid Y] = E[X]$ does not imply that $X$ is independent from $Y$, see for example this example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815227/is-there-any-counterexample-to-show-that-x-y-are-two-random-variables-and-ex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the random variables are discrete and the identity
$$P[A_n=a_n ; \ldots; A_1=a_1\mid A_0=a_0]=\prod_{j=1}^n P[A_j=a_j]\tag1$$
holds for **every** $a_0, a_1,\ldots,a_n$, then multiplying both sides of (1) by $P[A_0=a_0]$ yields
$$P\left(\bigcap_{j=0}^n \{A_j=a_j\}\right)=P[A_n=a_n ; \ldots; A_1=a_1\mid A_0=a_0]P[A_0=a_0]=\prod_{j=0}^n P[A_j=a_j]$$ for every $a_0,a_1,\ldots,a_n$ and therefore $A_0,A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are mutually independent by definition. In particular $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are mutually independent.